# How to run auto restart in heroku for ruby scripts

Tags: ruby, heroku, god

In my Dev box on Nitrous, I am able to run `God -c scripts.god -D` to restart the two .rb files if they die.

I just run that and the processes for the most part stay alive.

But I cannot do the same in heroku. It seems when I run the `god` command the .god file does not open and generates an error in heroku.

Question:

How can I run God to restart failed processes in heroku as I do on my development Nitrous environment?

Or is there a recommended alternative way to watch heroku processes and restart them automatically when they fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Heroku you shouldn't need to use a process supervisor like god. If all you need is to ensure your process is restarted if it crashes, Heroku can manage that fine.

It should be as simple as adding two entries in your procfile as workers. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

`worker: bundle exec sidekiq
clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
slack_listener: bundle exec ruby lib/slack_bot.rb`

You could possibly have issues, if your processing are crashing quite often. [Dyno Crash Restart Policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-crash-restart-policy)

Comment: I see. It doesn't crash often but it does. I will read up on sidekick.

Comment: Hi I didn't see anything on sidekiq. My app has a listener for input from Slack so needs to have the listener active and then run the script when it receives an inbound request. Sometimes the job that runs has issues so j want it to just restart since it means the input went awry.

Comment: The worker and clock are just examples. Sidekiq probably isn't what you want for a slack listener. You can basically type any command after the colon, and Heroku will ensure that the script is restarted if it ends or crashes.

Comment: Ah okay. I see now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your processes should start automatically when you access your website.

However, Heroku does provide commands to manage your processes, check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos for the complete list. E.g., to restart all processes, use the toolbelt command:

```
heroku ps:restart --app yourappname
```

Comment: I want it to start automatically without me when the script crashes. These looks like a manual process?